# Restrict to two specific domains @ Cognito with google login

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, amazon-cognito, google-signin

I'm using cloudfront triggering a lambda function to authenticate within cognito.

My Cognito is using google integration for login.

I Would like to restrict to **two domains**: my-company.com and my-company.io

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, its pretty straight forward.

1. Setup a Cognito Pre-signup Trigger (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-sign-up.html)
2. The trigger will call a lambda function with an event object, the event contains the email address of the user trying to sign. So, in the lambda get the event, extract the email address and compare it with your domains. If you want to allow the sign-up return the event. If you want to reject the sign-up, return a string (error message).

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer suggests it can be done with a lambda function setup as Pre sign-up trigger in the User pool properties. Example solution in Python with commented print statements for debugging:

```
import json
restricted_domains = ('my-company.com', 'my-company.io')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # allow only specific domains
    
    # Send data to Cloudwatch logs
    # print ("Pre signup successful")
    # print("Received context: ", context.__dict__)
    # print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
    
    email = event['request']['userAttributes']['email']
    domain = email.split('@')[1]
    if domain not in restricted_domains:
        raise Exception('Required email domain not fulfilled')
         
    return event
```